# Авторизация в laravel без make:auth

Tags: laravel, авторизация

делаю проект на laravel. Нужна авторизация. Знаю что есть make:auth, но мне его функционал не нужен. Вы не знаете как в laravel правильно авторизовать пользователя(coookie или session, какие параметры надо передать и как). Или возможно есть встроенная функция которая авторизует пользователя?

Comment: Тогда какой функционал вам нужен? Изобрести свой велосипед чтобы что? Встроенная функция которая авторизовывает пользователя и будет то что вам не нужно. Если вам необходима авторизация по JWT токена или ещё чуть сложнее тогда уж Laravel Passport. Смотря чего вы хотите добиться, опять же, написать собственную авторизацию? Так в чём проблема? Создаёте миграцию базы данных, создаёте контроллеры, модели, с чем именно проблемы? Больше чем уверен что ваша задача решается с использованием встроенной авторизации, нужно лишь правильно её использовать, как вам нужно